# Fix indentation after a multiline HTML tag

Tags: indentation, filetype-html

I have the following in `.vimrc`:

```
set tabstop=2 softtabstop=-1 shiftwidth=0 expandtab
filetype plugin indent on
```

When I type the following in an HTML file:

```
<html id="somethingverylong"
>
<head>
```

I expect the following indentation:

```
<html id="somethingverylong"
      >
  <head>
```

I want `<head>` to be indented two spaces. However, I get the following indentation:

```
<html id="somethingverylong"
      >
      <head>
```

How do I make Vim respect the `shiftwidth` setting and indent the inner tag with 2 spaces, instead of aligning with the closing `>`?

Vim version:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Aug  2 2016 05:21:06)
Included patches: 1-2143
Compiled by Arch Linux
```

Comment: Why are you adding a newline before the first closing `>`? That seems both unnecessary and very ugly!

Comment: @KarlYngveLervåg this is a simplified example. In the actual file, the outer tag has a lot of attributes aligned one under another.

Comment: You're setting `shiftwidth` twice; The first one should probably be `tabstop`. At any rate, what you want doesn't seem supported by the html indent file. You can try and fix it by manually editing `/usr/share/vim/vim74/indent/html.vim`.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker was indeed `tabstop`.